# Increment integer in NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, integer, nsuserdefaults

Is there a more elegant way to increment a counter stored in user defaults?

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setInteger(defaults.integerForKey("counter")+1, forKey: "counter")
```

Comment: No, it isn't. But maybe you could use a local counter and write to user defaults when leaving a controller or quitting the app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No but if you do this a lot it might make a nice extension, something like this.

```
extension NSUserDefaults {
    class func incrementIntegerForKey(key:String) {
        let defaults = standardUserDefaults()
        let int = defaults.integerForKey(key)
        defaults.setInteger(int+1, forKey:key)
    }
}
```

Usage like this

```
NSUserDefaults.incrementIntegerForKey("counter")
```

Comment: I continue to be impressed with the possibilities of extensions. I went for a version of this, which I'll post as a separate answer.

Comment: I would add a `defaults.synchronize()` statement at the end of this function. If one wants to perform several such operations in shorter amount of time, there is no guarantee that the value is immediately updated.

Answer (score 5):

This is the same as the solution offered by Wezly, but it reuses my global `defaults` object and and allows me to modify the value.

```
extension NSUserDefaults {
    func incrementIntegerForKey(key:String, by: Int) {
        let int = integerForKey(key)
        setInteger(int + by, forKey:key)
    }
}
```

Used like so (assuming you've defined defaults elsewhere):

```
defaults.incrementIntegerForKey("counter", by: -3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UserDefaults {
    class func incrementIntegerForKey(key: String) -> Int {
        let defaults = UserDefaults()
        let int = defaults.integer(forKey: key)
        defaults.setValue(int + 1, forKey: key)
        return int + 1
    }
}
```

Swift 5.1 also with return value for current increment