# Swift: How to create an event after X number of times a view controller is loaded

Tags: ios, swift

The answer to this question may be obvious but I was wondering if it is possible to create an event such as an alert or popup when a view controller is segued to after X number of times e.g. the third time a view controller is loaded a PopUp appears, as I can't seem to find anything about this online.

The event should be a one off occurrence and once has been triggered then it should not happen again.

Comment: You can save your count in userdefaults & can do whatever you want accessing that.

Comment: Is this within one session or can the app be closed between these events?

Comment: How would I add the count to userDefaults? the app can be closed between the events

Comment: buddy userdefaults holds the data even the app is closed or the device is restarted. You can check for X number & perform your action.

Comment: So something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379691/increment-integer-in-nsuserdefaults

Comment: [`UserDefaults` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults)

Comment: I'm just curious about the User Experience. What is exactly is the pop up you are thinking? I may be a bad idea to do such entirely or is that you are just trying to learn something right now?

Comment: Its an app where after they complete for example 3 workouts it asks them if they would like to leave a review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code, how can u use `NSUserDefaults` to do something like you described.

You need the value stored by an identifier in `NSUserDefaults`, easiest is as an `integer`.

Whenever you call `increaseViewLoadedCount()`, it will increase the counter's value, e.g. a view has been loaded.

Whenever you call `shouldShowAlert()`, we read the value from defaults, check it against some value, and return a `boolean` based on that.

Also, the `NSUserdefaults` are being synchronised, therefore even if the app is terminated, the counter value will be kept.

```
extension UserDefaults {
    /// Indetifier of counter container in `defaults` 
    private static let kCounterIdentifier = "counter"

    /// Count of loads after the alert should not be loaded
    private static let notDisplayAlertAfterCount = 3

    /// Increase the counter value
    func increaseViewLoadedCount() {
        guard let counterValue = value(forKey: UserDefaults.kCounterIdentifier) as? Int else {
            syncronizeCounter(with: 1) 
            return
        }
        syncronizeCounter(with: counterValue + 1) 
    }

    /// Reset the value to zero in Userdaults
    func resetViewLoadedCount() {
        syncronizeCounter(with: 0)
    }

    /// Check weather the alert should be presented or not
    ///
    /// - Returns: true if counter is smaller than notDisplayAlertAfterCount, false if greater
    func shouldShowAlert() -> Bool {
        guard let counterValue = value(forKey: UserDefaults.kCounterIdentifier) as? Int else {
            return true
        }

        // Set the number anything you like
        return counterValue < UserDefaults.notDisplayAlertAfterCount ? true : false
    }

    private func syncronizeCounter(with value: Int) {
        set(value, forKey: UserDefaults.kCounterIdentifier)
        synchronize()
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
print(defaults.shouldShowAlert()) // prints true
defaults.increaseViewLoadedCount()
defaults.increaseViewLoadedCount()
print(defaults.shouldShowAlert()) // prints true
defaults.increaseViewLoadedCount()
print(defaults.shouldShowAlert()) // prints false
```

Comment: small note in your test, it should have two lots of loadManager.increaseViewLoadedCount() instead of 3 otherwise it prints false on the second call to shouldShowAlert

Comment: @RyanHampton updated the solution using extension on `NSUserDefaults`. Should be more simple.